# What's wrong with this Javascript multi-field sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/hqg2zae8/) is my code:

```
<div class="item" data-count="1" data-title="C">1 C</div>
<div class="item" data-count="2" data-title="D">2 D</div>
<div class="item" data-count="2" data-title="A">2 A</div>
<div class="item" data-count="1" data-title="Z">1 Z</div>

$('.item').sort(function (x, y) {
    var n = $(x).attr("data-count") - $(y).attr("data-count");
    if (n != 0) {
        return n;
    }

    return $(x).attr("data-title") - $(y).attr("data-title");
});
```

I want to order the `.item` first for `data-count` decrescending, then for `data-title` ascending.

I.e. the result must be:

```
2 A
2 D
1 C
1 Z
```

but instead is:

```
1 C
2 D
2 A
1 Z
```

where am I wrong with this sort function?

Comment: Running `.sort()` on the jQuery object doesn't actually move the elements within the DOM, it just reorders them within the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this sort function. It works for me.

Html.

```
<div class="testWrapper">
    <div class="item" data-count="1" data-title="C">1 C</div>
    <div class="item" data-count="2" data-title="D">2 D</div>
    <div class="item" data-count="2" data-title="A">2 A</div>
    <div class="item" data-count="1" data-title="Z">1 Z</div>
</div>
```

Javascript.

```
var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');

$wrapper.find('.item').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +b.getAttribute('data-count') - +a.getAttribute('data-count') ||  a.getAttribute('data-title') > b.getAttribute('data-title');
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

Check my example. https://jsfiddle.net/88k8kbsz/

Answer (score 0):

There are three main issues that we can address:

- To compare count, we should use `parseInt` to compare ints instead of strings.
- To compare strings, we should use `localeCompare` to get 0, 1, or -1 instead of subtracting strings.
- After sorting the element array, we need to replace the existing elements with the sorted elements.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahL1Lgvo/) showing how to do the above.

```
function parse(node) {
    return {
        // Parse integer from attribute
        count: parseInt($(node).attr("data-count"), 10),
        title: $(node).attr("data-title")
    };
}

var items = $('.item').toArray().sort(function (x, y) {
    var xData = parse(x);
    var yData = parse(y);
    if (xData.count !== yData.count) {
        return xData.count - yData.count;
    }

    // Compare strings
    return xData.title.localeCompare(yData.title);
});

// Replace existing children with sorted children
$('.container').empty();
$('.container').append(items);
```

Comment: Your first issue isn't an issue in this case. The `-` operator converts its operands to numbers.

Comment: `+` can perform addition or concatenation, however, `-` can only perform subtraction and its operands are automatically converted to numbers.